# fire change event on a multiline text box (enhanced rich text) in SharePoint using jquery

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, jquery

I have a list (MyList) with some columns. It also contains a column (Mydesc) which is a multiline text box having enhanced rich text. Now in the edit form I have to check whether any change occurs in the form. For every other column I can capture the change event but not for my "Mydesc" column.
 I tried this code but failing.

```
    $("#Mydesc_aede8400-1a1f-4071-b97a-188d2980b7b1_$TextField").keydown(function() {
alert('Testing...');
});
```

Error message is:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #Mydesc_aede8400-1a1f-4071-b97a-188d2980b7b1_$TextField

Answer (score 0):

Your selector has a special character $ and it must be escaped with

```
two backslashes: \\

To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar").
```

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Also tried to fetch the ID using this statement

Comment: $("textarea[Title='MyDesc']").closest("span").find("iframe[Title='Rich Text Editor']")